# Generating Sublists of a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm new to haskell and was trying to write a function to generate a powerset which only includes consecutive subsets
eg: [1,2,3] -> [[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3]]

I found this on a blog http://davidtran.doublegifts.com/blog/?p=7

```
powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset []     = [[]]
powerset (x:xs) = powerset xs ++ map (x:) (powerset xs)
-- powerset (x:xs) = powerset xs ++ [x:xs' | xs' <- powerset xs]
```

but this generates all the subsets i.e [1,3] included which i dont want?
is there anyway to fix this code to work or do I have to rethink my approach.
Also i do not want to use built in library functions, wanna get my basics right.

Comment: What do you mean by 'consecutive subsets'?

Comment: i mean [1,2] [2,3] but not [1,3]

Comment: As a matter of terminology: I usually see people use the term *substring* to refer to the "consecutive subsets" and the term *subsequence* for the not necessarily consecutive subsets.

Comment: @missingno: That makes perfect sense! I somehow had the (silly) idea that the subsets *themselves* must be consecutive (or that you could get from [1,2] to [2,3] by 'adding 1'), not the elements they contain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like

```
conseqPower = ([] :) . concatMap (tail . inits) . tails
```

Comment: i'll try this, but i was rather hoping not to use 2 functions

Comment: Well, you can write your own.  But it's more convenient to just reuse existing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the non-"consecutive" lists.

Comment: can i get some code not sure how to filter, or some link to filter function?

Comment: This approach appears to require `Eq a`, and still seems difficult in the presence of duplicate items in the list (e.g. consider `powerset "hello"`).

Comment: @dave4420 Given that the example is a sequence of distinct integer, I'm not sure this matters for OPs case.

Comment: That's a pretty bad idea algorithmically speaking though... since his function produce much less output (2 amongst n, so n^2) than powerset (2^n), it's pretty absurd to go to the pain of producing all powersets just to filter out the immense majority of them.

Comment: @Jedai Sure, but this a solution, and one that can be implemented easily. No doubt you will agree that is better than no solution whatsoever.

Comment: @Marcin : True, but is it so easy to implement ? On the example list sure, but on an arbitrary list to check if the elements are consecutive, you'll need to pair the element with their index, then re-extract the elements from the pair as post-treatment. That's still better that no solution of course, but since directly coding a solution that won't takes hours to handle a 100-element list is not really hard in this case... :) I would say that generating a superset and filtering out the unwanted elements is only acceptable if you don't completely change the class of complexity (n^2 = o(2^n))...

Comment: @Jedai Yes, it is so easy to implement. You would not need to go through the weirdly convoluted process you suggest. You could zip the list on itself (shifted by one), for example. In any case, I maintain this is much better than your completely non-existent answer.

Comment: @Marcin : Why would I add an answer that has already been given correctly by augustss : take all the tails of the list and extract all their initial parts with inits (then some details). By the way you didn't give your so easy answer either. And you still fail to grasp the crux of my objection : your answer isn't "practical" as you would imply by saying "better a slow solution than none", simply because powerset whatever its implementation isn't practical beyond very small lists (20-30 elts top) whereas any solution should work for list of reasonable size (>1000).

Comment: Just to be clear it's perfectly acceptable to me to generate 100 times more elements than what you'll keep after filtering for instance. But here we're not at this point : for an initial list of 10 elements, we'll keep 1 in 20, for 20 elements, we'll keep 1 in 5000, for 30, 1 in 2,000,000 , for 40, 1 in 1,000,000,000... for 100 we'll keep 1 in 2*10^26 !!

Comment: @Jedai Would you like me to come visit all of your answers, and complain that they don't meet requirements that I just made up? If you want to complain about answers that don't meet your requirements, go ask your own question, and include your requirements there. Don't bother me with them.